# cakephp output data as json

Tags: cakephp, json

I am new to cakephp and i am trying to create a simple rest api that deals with vehicles. I want to out my data that i get from mysql database in json format.

**This is my controller**

```
class VehiclesController extends AppController {
    var $name = 'Vehicles';
    var $layout = 'default';

    function index() {
        $this->set('vehicles', $this->Vehicle->find('all'));
        $this->set('title_for_layout','Home');
    }
}
```

How would i out the content as json in a view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a view here `Views/Vehicles/json/index.ctp`.

In your view you should be able to use:

```
<?php echo json_encode($vehicles); ?>
```

To output the JSON

You can then access it on this url : `/vehicles/index.json`

Comment: hi thanks, it works. But should it come out as one line of text